# UI/template module not found NativeScript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, arrays, nativescript

I keep getting the following error in regards to the ui/template module:

```
file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js:195:56: JS ERROR Error: Building UI from XML. @file:///app/main-page.xml:38:13
     > Module 'ui/template' not found for element 'Template'.
       > Could not find module 'ui/template'. Computed path
```

For some reason, I can not use the `<template>` tag in NativeScript for the following code:

```
 <GridLayout>

  <ListView items="{{ groceryList }}" itemTemplateProperty="list-group" itemTap="navigateToTasks" separatorColor="white">
        <ListView.itemTemplate>
            <template>
                <Label text="{{ name }}" class="list-group-item-heading"  />
            </template>
            <template>
                <Label text="{{ grocery }}" class="list-group-item-heading"  />
            </template>
        </ListView.itemTemplate>

    </ListView> 
</GridLayout>
```

I build the array as the following:

```
var pageData = new observableModule.fromObject({
    groceryList: new ObservableArray([
        { name: "Cool" },
        { name: "bread" },
        { name: "cereal"},
        { grocery: "id"}
            ])
});
```

For some reason, I can also not include the ui/template module as it is not found. I tried to put the following in main-page.js:

```
var ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;
```

But it's apparently not working.

Comment: same problem here... any solution found?

Answer (score 4):

It took me a while to figure this out, but as soon as you introduce multiple templates, you need to change ListView.itemTemplate to ListView.itemTemplate**s** (i.e. the 's' at the end!)

```
 <GridLayout>

  <ListView items="{{ groceryList }}" itemTemplateProperty="list-group" itemTap="navigateToTasks" separatorColor="white">
        <ListView.itemTemplates>
            <template>
                <Label text="{{ name }}" class="list-group-item-heading"  />
            </template>
            <template>
                <Label text="{{ grocery }}" class="list-group-item-heading"  />
            </template>
        </ListView.itemTemplates>

    </ListView> 
</GridLayout>
```